# R: data.table, aggregate data frame by column names stored in variables

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a data frame like the `iris` one:

```
> data(iris)
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

I want to aggregate the data frame so that I obtain the mean value of `Sepal.Width` for each `Species`, for example. In that case I would do:

```
> library(data.table)
> dd <- data.table(iris)
> dagg <- as.data.frame(dd[, list(Mean.value=mean(Sepal.Width)), by=list(ID=Species)])
> dagg
          ID Mean.value
1     setosa      3.428
2 versicolor      2.770
3  virginica      2.974
```

However, the case I am facing now is that that is part of a function, and I do it for different data frames and different columns.

So now I have column names stored in variables, so I try:

```
> idvar <- "Species"
> valvar <- "Sepal.Width"
> dd <- data.table(iris)
> dagg <- as.data.frame(dd[, list(Mean.value=mean(iris[,valvar])), by=list(ID=iris[,idvar])])
> dagg
          ID Mean.value
1     setosa   3.057333
2 versicolor   3.057333
3  virginica   3.057333
```

The result is clearly wrong; what would be the way to do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it's the cleanest way, but you could use `.SDcols=` - `dd[, .(Mean.value = mean(.SD[[1]])), by=idvar, .SDcols=valvar]`

Comment: @thelatemail, a variant of your code with `..x` syntax also works: `dd[, .(Mean.value = mean(.SD[[..valvar]])), by=idvar]`

Comment: It would be better to do it in two steps in order to exploit the `GForce` optimization of `data.table`: `res <- dd[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = idvar, .SDcols = valvar]; setnames(res, c('ID', 'Mean.value'))`.

Comment: @mt1022 - indeed, on both counts. You're popping up helpful everywhere for me lately :-) I gather `dd[, .(mean.value = mean(get(valvar))), by=idvar]` likewise stuffs up the GForce optim?

Comment: @thelatemail, with `verbose = T`, I saw "Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE)". It seems `data.table` is not smart enough to optimize the `j` expression with `get`.

Comment: Could also just do `data.table(iris)[, mean(get(valvar)), by = idvar]`. Not sure how is the dyplr solution is so much cleaner than this

Comment: @DavidArenburg that is exactly what I was looking for! `dagg <- as.data.frame(dd[, list(Mean.value=mean(get(valvar))), by=list(ID=get(idvar))])` I did not know about `get`. If you want to develop that into an answer, that should be the accepted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to consider `dplyr` instead of `data.table`, here's a solution using [tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

```
library(dplyr)
idvar  <- "Species"
valvar <- "Sepal.Width"

iris %>% 
  group_by(!!sym(idvar)) %>% 
  summarise(Mean.value = mean(!!sym(valvar)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    Mean.value
  <fct>           <dbl>
1 setosa           3.43
2 versicolor       2.77
3 virginica        2.97
```

Comment: I like this dplyr solution, so clean

Comment: It took me a while to get my head around tidy evaluation, but when you realise it's just "converting between strings and symbols", it starts to make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap `.SDcols` and `by` within `c()` to pass columns as strings.

```r
library(data.table)
dd <- data.table(iris)

aggregator <- function(DT, col2avg, new.name = "avg", by = NULL) {
  out <- 
    if (is.null(by)) {
      DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c(col2avg)][]
    } else {
      DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c(col2avg), by = c(by)][]
    }
  setnames(out, col2avg, new.name)
  out[]
}

aggregator(dd, col2avg = "Sepal.Width", by = "Species", new.name = "Mean.value")
#>       Species Mean.value
#> 1:     setosa      3.428
#> 2: versicolor      2.770
#> 3:  virginica      2.974
```

(plus an extra `setnames(out, by, "ID")` if you need).

Using `by = c(by)` rather than `by = by` makes it explicit that the RHS is a string representing a column name, as `data.table` will first look for a column called `"by"` regardless of `by`'s value outside the table.

Comment: If I remove the `c()`'s from your `aggregator` function, I get exactly the same result.

Comment: Sure but if you have a column called “col2avg” or “by” you need to distinguish

Comment: Wise - that wasn't obvious from the answer, but that makes a lot of sense.